I can't upgrade JSON field in my db model
I am using flask-sqlalchemy with sqlite3 and I can't upgrade a json field, model:
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(18), nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(18), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(125), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False) 
    wish_list = db.Column(db.JSON)
    is_company = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

from main.models import User
from main import db 

user = User.query.get(1)
user.wish_list #{'hotels': [1, 2]}
user.wish_list["hotels"] += [3]
db.session.commit()
user = User.query.get(1)
user.wish_list #{'hotels': [1, 2]} it is still the same why??

It should be {'hotels': [1, 2, 3]} then why does it return {'hotels': [1, 2]}?

Use the mutable extension - see the linked duplicate.
